# Continuous updates of storage change in AWS S3

Tags: spring, amazon-s3, scheduler, amazon-glacier

I have lifecycle rule enabled on s3, which moves objects to galcier after 30days. Since AWS does not support event notification yet, I don't have a way to update my application about object moving to glacier.

My use case is "Once object is moved to glacier, I want to restrict users from performing any action on that object". Is there a way to get update once object moves to S3?

I am planning to implement a scheduler (using spring @Scheduler) which will run every 1Hr and scan all objects in s3 and check if they have moved to glacier then update application RDS accordingly.

Let me know if there are other good approaches to handle this use case instead of writing a scheduler.

Regards.

Comment: How many number of files on average you moved to glacier in 30 days time?

Comment: If you want to *"restrict users from performing any action on that object"* in your application, you could simply block those actions when the object is 30 days old, because if it isn't in glacier yet, it will be within a matter of hours.  What operations do you want to block?  Some operations won't work, anyway, because objects in the glacier storage class aren't compatible with those operations.  It depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: When you say "I want to restrict users", are these *application users*, or *IAM Users*?

Comment: Asset that we manage in system are media files, so they can use this files from s3 and transcode it to different format. Since, files are moved to glacier it won't be available to transcode. They also have option to download this files which also won't work if asset is archived. So I need to restrict such actions from application.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to get update once object moves to S3?

At the moment, there is no S3 event support for this.

> Let me know if there are other good approaches to handle this use case
>   instead of writing a scheduler.

The approach you are planning to use, seems reasonable. For the scheduler, you can use a Lambda function with scheduled events without putting the burden to your current server.

Comment: Thanks Ashan, I will explore more on lambda. To give you more insights, users will have option to restore archived files for requested no of days. Once restored they can perform actions like download that file, or transcode is to different format. Once restored object expires asset will be moved back to galcier. So, I need to reflect all these status in application so user can see if asset is available to perform any operation or not. Let me know if you have any such examples which I can look into and take reference from.